# Game Engine Multithreading with Lua

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua

I'm designing the threading architecture for my game engine, and I have reached a point where I am stumped.

The engine is partially inspired by Grimrock's engine, where they put as much as they could into LuaJIT, with some things, including low level systems, written in C++.

This seemed like a good plan, given that LuaJIT is easy to use, and I can continue to add API functions in C++ and expand it further. Faster iteration is nice, the ability to have a custom IDE attached to the game and edit the code while it runs is an interesting option, and serializing from Lua is also easy.

But I am stumped on how to go about adding threading. I know Lua has coroutines, but that is not true threading; it's basically to keep Lua from stalling as it waits for code that takes too long.

I originally had in mind to have the main thread running in Lua and calling C++ functions which are dispatched to the scheduler, but I can't find enough information on how Lua functions. I do know that when Lua calls a C++ function it runs outside of the state, so theoretically it *may* be possible.

I also don't know whether, if Lua makes such a call that is not supposed to return anything, it will hang on the function until it's done.

And I'm not sure whether the task scheduler runs in the main thread, or if it is simply all worker threads pulling data from a queue.

Basically meaning that, instead of everything running at once, it waits for the game state update before doing anything.

Does anyone have any ideas, or suggestions for threading?

Comment: So, this question is quite broad right now. You might want to split it up into some simpler, very specific questions that an expert can unambiguously answer. The more squishy / design issues should probably go on gamedev stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a single `lua_State *` is not thread safe. It's written in pure C and meant to go very fast. It's not safe to allow exceptions go through it either. There's no locks in there and no way for it to protect itself.

If you want to run multiple lua scripts simultaneously in separate threads, the most straightforward way is to use `luaL_newstate()` separately in each thread, initialize each of them, and load and run scripts in each of them. They can talk to the C++ safely as long as your callbacks use locks when necessary. At least, that's how I would try to do it.

There are various things you could do to speed it up, for instance, if you are loading copies of a single script in each of the threads, you could compile it to lua bytecode before you launch any of the threads, then put the buffer into shared memory, and have the scripts load the shared byte code without changing. That's most likely an unnecessary optimization though, depending on your application.

Comment: I'm aware that Lua is not thread safe. But I don't plan on having tasked based functions actually return data to Lua.

In such the case where lua streams an audio file from disk. For most situations, the programmer shouldn't have to care if he gets data back. So Lua should just delegate the task to another thread to work on while it continues on it's business. If the programmer does need to hold onto the data, than he can just assign a Coroutine to wait on it.

I have thought about different LUA states, but I'm looking to avoid that for now.

Comment: What I would want to do then is make a system in C++ so that you can have a callback which dispatches a thread to take care of some audio. And register that callback with the main lua thread. Why do you want these threads to run in the exact same lua state as the original? If they are writing to shared variables its probably going to cause data races with the other threads. If they are reading shared variables it is still likely to cause data races. Even if you can find some situations in which it seems to work, it's going to make your life really hard I think.

Comment: Sorry minor miscommunication at late hours. I don't want to make threads in the Lua state. Just keep Lua on the main thread and it dispatches C++ functions to other cores. I was wondering if it was possible to send C++ code to a completely different core, from Lua for async. I thought about the callback, but I was not sure if that was possible. Then again...just pass data from the callback to another function that is tied to the task system, right?